# Solr query must match all words/tokens in a field

Tags: solr

I have a text-field called `name` in my `schema.xml`. A query `q=name:(organic)` returns the following documents:

```xml
<doc>
    <str name="id">ontology.category.1483</str>
    <str name="name">Organic Products</str>
</doc>
<doc>
    <str name="id">ontology.keyword.4896</str>
    <str name="name">Organic Stores</str>
</doc>
```

This is perfectly right in a normal Solr Search, **however** I would like to construct the query so that it doesn't return anything because *'organic'* only matches 1 of the 2 words available in the field.

A better way to say it could be this: Only return results if all tokens in the field are matched. So if there are two words (tokens) in a field and I only match 1 (*'organic'*, *'organics'*,*'organ'* etc.) I shouldn't get a match because only 50% of the field has been searched on.

Is this possible in Solr?  How do I construct the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to time contraints, I had to resort to the following (hacky) solution.

I added the term count to the index via a DynamicField field called `tc_i`.

```xml
<dynamicField name="*_i" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Now at query time I count the terms and append it to the query, so `q=name:(organic)` becomes `q=name:(organic) AND tc_i:(1)` and this won't return documents for "organic stores" / "organic products" obviously because their `tc_i` fields are set at 2 (two words).

Answer (score 0):

you are probably using StandardTokenizerFactory (or something similar), one solution is to use KeywordTokenizerFactory and issue a phrase query and then only perfect matches will work. Of course remember other filters you might want to use (like LowerCaseFilterFactory etc). Note that: "stores organic" will not match your doc either

Comment: Hi raticulin, I would have used the KeywordTokenizerFactory but I need the lemmatization on the field. eg. "organics store" MUST hit "organic stores" etc.